# Reversing the order of items in a category rss feed?

Tags: categories, rss, feed

Is there an easy way to reverse the default item order of a category rss feed?

```
Default: Last posted item first
Wanted: First posted item first
```

No plugins please, plain wp api function calls (such as add_action or add_filter) will do!

Comment: "plain wp php" is a plugin or a theme or any other bit of functionality that you add outside of WordPress' core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply reorder your RSS Feed via the GET parameter `?order=ASC` or `?order=DESC` after your FEED url!

Answer (score 0):

In your functions.php file

```
function reverseorder($query_string)  
{
    return query_posts( $query_string . '&order=ASC' );
}
add_action( 'rss2_head', 'reverseorder' );
```

**EDIT**

GET parameters on RSS feed
cat - category ID (e.g. 23)
author - author ID (e.g. 14)
year - year the post was published (e.g. 2007)
day - day of the month the post was published (e.g. 17)
monthnum - number of the month the post was published (e.g. 6)
hour - hour of the day the post was published (e.g. 23)
minute - minute of the hour the post was published (e.g. 48)
second - second of the minute the post was published (e.g. 51)
p - the unique post ID to display (e.g. 629)
paged - specific page number as displayed on the main blog page (e.g. 3)

Comment: @mahatmanich Who is your comment for up there? If it worked, please mark as correct answer.

Comment: The comment was for the other Chris that was being a smart alec. I am still looking at the solution you posted here however it does not quite work in my instance!

Comment: Basically you need to reverse the order of the feed-rss2.php file using that action on line (36?)

Comment: Actually I could just use the GET parameter when calling the feed couldn't I?

Comment: Hmm, to my knowledge ordering of RSS feed is not a get parameter.

Comment: Updated my answer with a list

Comment: you are using a get parameter, try &order=ASC or &order=DES on a wp feed!